# Azure B2C login with Cypress using cy.request()

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, cypress, azure-ad-b2c, cypress-login

Our app requires Azure b2c authentication when login in. I automated the login by simply typing the username and password. In addition  I had to add "chromeWebSecurity": false to avoid cross-origin issue.

I think this is the incorrect way of login in. While I was searching for a solution I came across some articles regarding this. Apparently we could user Cy.request() and get the response and then access the app.

However, I was unable to implement this.

Has anyone implemented the Azure b2c login automation with cypress ? if so can someone explain how this needs to be done ?

Our app uses access bearer tokens.
It first sends authentication requests
GET https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
Then gets the token
POST https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant}.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/token

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too familiar with Azure b2c authentication, but looks like the general pattern is given here [How to use Cypress to test your SharePoint solution with an Azure AD-secured API](https://www.eliostruyf.com/cypress-test-sharepoint-solution-azure-ad-secured-api/)

The bulk of the code is this

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("visitWithAdal", (pageUrl) => { 
  const config = {
    username: process.env.CI ? Cypress.env('USERNAME') : Cypress.env('username'),
    password: process.env.CI ? Cypress.env('PASSWORD') : Cypress.env('password'),
    tenant: process.env.CI ? Cypress.env('TENANT') : Cypress.env('tenant'),
    clientId: process.env.CI ? Cypress.env('CLIENTID') : Cypress.env('clientid'),
    clientSecret: process.env.CI ? Cypress.env('CLIENTSECRET') : Cypress.env('clientsecret'),
    resource: process.env.CI ? Cypress.env('RESOURCE') : Cypress.env('resource')
  };

  // Fetch the access token for the Microsoft Graph
  cy.request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `https://login.microsoft.com/${config.tenant}/oauth2/token`,
    header: {
       'cache-control': 'no-cache',
       'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    form: true,
    body: {
      grant_type: 'password',
      client_id: config.clientId,
      client_secret: config.clientSecret,
      resource: config.resource,
      password: config.password,
      username: config.username
    }
  }).then(response => {
    if (response && response.status === 200 && response.body) {
      const accessToken = response.body["access_token"];
      const expires = response.body["expires_on"];
      // Store the retrieved access token in the session storage
      cy.window().then((crntWindow) => {
        crntWindow.sessionStorage.setItem(`adal.token.keys`, `${config.resource}|`);
        crntWindow.sessionStorage.setItem(`adal.expiration.key${config.resource}`, expires);
        crntWindow.sessionStorage.setItem(`adal.access.token.key${config.resource}`, accessToken);
        
        cy.visit(pageUrl);
      });
    }
  });
});
```